# Introducing test-driven development to legacy code

Tags: java, oop, tdd, design-principles

Given: A `LegacyControllerClass` that extends a `MonsterFrameworkClass` (part of a very yucky framework that people are just living with for years). Framework class does lots of magic ranging from tons of logic in the default constructor to static blocks that reflectively load classes.

Lots of life-cycle methods in `LegacyControllerClass`, which mutate global states. The `execute()` method is a thousand-liner that has all the evils that you can think of.

```
public class LegacyControllerClass extends MonsterFrameworkClass {

   //Life-cycle method
   public void validate(){...}

   //Life-cycle method
   public void preExecute() {...}

   //Life-cycle method
   public void execute() {
       //oodles of legacy code here:
       //    examples: call static methods of 'Util' classes
       //              lots of new X().y(..)
       //              call databases, services
       //              Even call super.execute()!!
       //              More rubbish
       //              More rubbish 
   }
}
```

Okay, now the scene of action is the execute() method. I'm introducing Test-Driven-Development to these have-nots, by test-driving an item what they call as a 'story'. The 'story' involves adding an error message to the responseProperties so that the view(jsp) can read it off and display. The pseudo-code is something like:

```
if (error) {
    Build the error message
    Add the error message into the responseProperties
}
```

This code unfortunately has to be sand-witched between the rubbish in the `execute()` method.

My question is: what is the best thing I can do? 
The solution I could come up is:

1. extracting two methods `rubbish1()` and `rubbish2()`
2. stub them out in my test code with whatever expectations (Eg;- set the error flag)
3. Put my code between `rubbish1()` and `rubbish2()`

I started implementing it this way, but the `MonsterFrameworkClass` is really getting in my way: like static loads, constructor magic that loads up a `ResourceBundle` of random properties files, etc.

Are there alternate ways of dealing with the same?

**Teeny-tiny Disclaimer**: I am definitely going to buy Michael Feather's "Working with Legacy Code" and gulp it down, but SO seemed to be a low-hanging fruit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactoring the **rubbish** into methods is fine. Now you can download Powermock to mock out all the **terrible rubbish** in the code. After you are done with mocking you can test your code.

It is even better if you refrain from adding anything to this monstrosity. You can compose your functionality into `MonstrosityRubbish` (or whatever) by writing your own classes for the new stuff.

The main thing is not to touch any of the legacy code if possible, you can compose your code into it instead.

So in code:

```
private MyShinyClass yourShinyObject; // init

public void execute(Param param0) {
    rubbish1();
    yourShinyObject.handleError(param0);
    rubbish2();
}

public class MyShinyClass {

    public void handleError(Param param0) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

If you can manage to write your new stuff like this you will only depend on `Param` which can be mocked/stubbed and your code can be tested without setting your hair on fire.

It is even better if you can write it in a functional way so you don't have to manipulate `responseProperties` in your separated code:

```
public void execute(Param param0) {
    rubbish1();
    responseProperties.add(yourShinyObject.fetchErrors(param0));
    rubbish2();
}

public class MyShinyClass {

    public List<HopelessError> fetchErrors(Param param0) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Of course `execute()` does not need a parameter you can pass any variable/field you want to `handleErrors()`.

Comment: I was using mockito before. I'll definitely read up on powermock: Do you think it can address the static library loads of super-classes, the resource bundle declarations, etc.?

Comment: Yes. Powermock builds on Mockito and it is able to handle all this rubbish Mockito is not able to. They can interoperate so you don't have to refactor much when you start using Powermock.

Comment: The catch with PowerMock is that it is _so_ powerful at stuff like this. If you do this a lot without being disciplined about refactoring away pieces of the legacy mess each time, then you end up with a lot of 'hidden' dependencies in your tests. The rubbish spreads!